# Any rumors that ios maps api will provide routes

Tags: ios, mapkit

After the iOS 7 introduction, are there rumors whether the maps api will provide native routing  or will one still have to go through a 3rd party?

Cheers,
EL

Comment: If you want to talk about iOS 7, I suggest you go check out the Apple Developer Forums https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios7_beta

Answer (score 2):

Not until now. You can ask them directly.. This is not place to share rumors which is wrong actually.

Or check from here:

https://developer.apple.com/ios7/